# Ramification in a composition of fields

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $L$ and $K$ number fields, if $p$ is ramified in $LK$ then it's ramified at $L$ or $K$?

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/71380

Comment: Yes. The compositum of two unramified extensions is unramified: both fields sit in the fixed field of the inertia group of the Galois closure of $LK$.